CUDA and Ubuntu and torch versions are conflicting
I am trying to set up a new computer to do some ML that I was previously doing on a HPC. I am now lost in dependencies conflicts. I run the code inside Apptainer containers.




(old) HPC
new computer




distro
Rocky 9.3 Blue Onyx
Ubuntu 24.04.1


kernel
5.14.0
6.8.0


CUDA version
12.1
12.6



When I run my code on the new computer I meet an error saying the CUDA version here does not match the one that Torch was compiled with (12.1). When I try to install CUDA 12.1 it tells me a dependency (libtinfo5) is missing. It seems the latest pytorch doesn't support the latest CUDA and the latest CUDA doesn't support the latest Ubuntu, but I found some conflicting information on this. Which one should I install or downgrade ?
For context, the full error  that happens when installing an older CUDA (even after adding the universe repo to the sources):
$ sudo apt-get install cuda-12-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nsight-systems-2023.1.2 : Depends: libtinfo5 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


https://gist.github.com/Hansimov/c2c82c9512245758398bc8b48c2789c0

... and the CUDA version depends on the Nvidia driver version (and the versions you can run depend on the specific GPU), not the Ubuntu release.
